# Haskell ReaderT Design Pattern vs mtl StateT pattern

Tags: haskell

I'm designing a small game which basically uses StateT and just updating the state. Below is the simplified version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Lens
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Control.Monad.State
import           Control.Monad.State.Class
import           System.Random

data PlayerState = PlayerState {
  _psName  :: String,
  _psScore :: Int
                               } deriving (Show)

makeClassy ''PlayerState

data Game = Game {
  _turns   :: Int,
  _players :: [PlayerState]
                 } deriving (Show)

makeClassy ''Game

randomGameInit :: IO Game
randomGameInit = do
  players <- replicateM 5 $  PlayerState <$> (replicateM 4 $ randomRIO ('a', 'z')) <*> randomRIO (1,10)
  return $ Game 0 players

update :: (MonadState s m, HasGame s) => m ()
update = do
  players . ix 0 . psName %= (\_ -> "mordor")
  turns %= (+1)
  exitCondition <- fmap (>10) (turns <%= id)
  unless exitCondition update

main :: IO ()
main = do
  init <- randomGameInit
  runStateT update init >> print "Game Over"
```

I've recently learned about the [ReaderT Design Pattern vs mtl StateT](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern), which encourages replacing `StateT` with a mutable reference inside a `ReaderT` over `IO`.

I wonder how I should adapt the code using ReaderT. Most specifically, many `Lens` functions have types: `(MonadState s m)` which apparently need to be inside a State. Does this mean that `Lens` library functions are designed for StateT and not ReaderT?  How to use `Lens` with `ReaderT` design pattern?

Comment: `ReaderT` won't let you update the state

Comment: If your `ReaderT` is over `IO`, you can keep a mutable reference in your environment and use it to store state. For an example of library that uses this trick, `RIO` has a `MonadState` instance when a `SomeRef` is in the environment http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.8.0/docs/RIO.html#t:RIO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've seen, ReaderT pattern users typically don't use the MonadState lens operators. Instead, use `view` to access the desired MVar (or whatever kind of mutable var you're dealing with) and update that as usual (e.g. with modifyMVar).

The RIO monad offers an appropriate MonadState instance, though. A better answer than mine could probably adapt your code to the RIO monad fairly easily.

Comment: Here's an example of doing this with rio: https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/ce5600bbc102cb0a70611e14ecdbf2ef

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Wow thanks, Michael! So honored to get a direct gist from you:)